# VBA Refresh all ribbons in Word, including that of the template

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word, ribbon

I have a Word macro-template that sits in STARTUP and becomes an Add-In. It creates a new ribbon tab on Word.

Other templates, e.g. Agenda.dotm, also have their own ribbon coding but they are set to share the new tab that the Add-In made so new buttons appear on the right of it.

It all works fine but I now have the need to swap between two languages. I have a button on the Add-In that toggles bewteen the languages and it calls Invalidate against it's ribbon to force it to refresh (the buttons use getLabel to fetch whatever language is active). That works.

What I am not sure how to do is tell the Agneda's ribbon to refresh itself?

Is there some way to tell Word to refresh ALL (custom) ribbons, not just the one attached to the current file?

Thanks

Simon